Outer edge path of raster image
I am asking for advice on the easiest way to create a code that will generate a path (SVG) of the outline of a PNG image that has transparency. It can be a Python script, or command line commands (image magick, potrace, etc).
Here is example. I have PNG transparent file and I want to get path out that outline for cutting device.

Edit: I scan image form every side to find first not transparent pixel (red point)

Then I draw line between everypoint and trim too long lines.

And the last step is to find contour over alpha channel.
And for star it looks pretty good


One issue may be that it is not a single outline. In the given picture it IS a single outline.
What you do is start in the upper left pixel and start scanning until you hit a non-transparent pixel. Keep an array of boolean image sized, and all true.
When you look at any pixel, turn it off in the mask. When you scan and hit a pixel look down, left for non-transparent pixels that have not already been visited.
Keep a linked list of X,Y coordinates, and add the adjacent edge pixel you find as you scan along the edge.
Then take the X,Y pairs and treat them as line points.

Not really sure what you actually are aiming for, but here are some steps with ImageMagick that should get you close. Don't worry that it is long, I am just showing you all the steps along the way and why I take them. You only really need the final command I show.
First extract the alpha channel:
magick YOURIMAGE.png -alpha extract alpha.png


Now try to get outer edge contour by floodfilling with red from the top-left corner:
magick alpha.png -fill red -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" b.png


That didn't work, because your shape touches the edges. So try adding a groove (i.e. black border) all around the edge that the floodfill can flow around:
magick alpha.png -bordercolor black -border 1 -fill red -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" b.png

Now try floodfilling again:
magick alpha.png -bordercolor black -border 1 -fill red -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" c.png


Ok, that's better. Now make everything that is not red black, and then make the red white:
magick alpha.png -bordercolor black -border 1 -fill red -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque red e.png


Now mark the edges of that shape:
magick alpha.png -bordercolor black -border 1 -fill red -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque red -edge 1 result.png



You can now pass that through potrace and get your outline, hopefully. Note that your image is now 2 pixels taller and 2 pixels wider (because I added a border) - you can remove these with -shave 1 as the last step of the processing.
Here is the full command:
magick YOURIMAGE.png -alpha extract -bordercolor black -border 1 -fill red -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque red -edge 1 result.png


It does not work, maybe there is some filename issues. Can you look?

Did you run the very first command, with -alpha extract in it? I added a complete, single command at the very end for simplicity.

Yes, I have  alpha.png,then it creates c.png e.png and empty result.png.
c.png has red background and e.png has white background and black object

Did you start with the exact same image as me? Is my final result correct and useful for your purposes?

The same and other and the result is blank transparent PNG

Is my final result correct and useful for your purposes?

Try adding -alpha off immediately after -edge 1

It works now, but potrace result is not smooth. I need to get back to python and opencv. The result is ok, but the SVG path is not as smooth as I need. Thanks anyway

You can use the same processing steps as above but with OpenCV by the way.

Can you look at my last edit of my answear below? I have successfully generated SVG path but it is too sharp. Do you have any idea how to make it smooth?
